# Spring, Collection of inner beans extended during runtime

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, runtime

I am a relatively new Spring user, and i am interested to use this framework to load a complex nested configuration.

The following is a pseudo code of my architecture design:

```
   class **A** implements runnable{
      int x;
      Collection<**B**> clist;         //not fixed size list, 
      run(){
           // if (something happens) 
           //           new Thread(**B**(y,z,w))
      }
   } 

   class **B** implements runnable{
      int y;
      int z;
      int w;
      Array<**C**> bclist;            // fixed size array of C known at init time
      run(){
           process...
      }
   } 

   class **C**{
      int v;
      int l;
   }
```

i need to be able to configure A.x, B.y , B.z, B.w , B.clist, C.v and C.l

I have a single problem that is relevant to the initialization of B for every new Thread, i don't know at compile time if clist will stay empty, and only at runtime i will know how many threads will be created. for every new thread i create new B with the same configuration.

(i looked over autowire and prototype features , and i suspect it somehow may help)

**EDIT**

Here i have xml example file:

```
            <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
            <beans>
                <bean id="A" class="...">
                    <property name="x" value="150" />
                    <!-- HERE IS MY PROBLEM-->

                    <property name="clist">
                        <list>
                            <ref bean="B" />
                        </list>
                </bean>

                <bean id="B" class="...">
                    <property name="y" value="20" />
                    <property name="z" value="7" />
                    <property name="w" value="7" />
                    <property name="bclist">
                        <list>
                            <ref bean="C" />
                        </list>
                </bean>

                <bean id="C" class="...">
                    <property name="v" value="3" />
                    <property name="l" value="1" />
                </bean>
            </beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a possible solution to this issue, it may be not optimal.

in the A bean in the xml i may comment out the setting of the clist (no including it at all in the structure),

and when i create in java code the B bean , i may use getBean("B") every time , while defining the B bean in the xml as prototype.

Like this :

```
            <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
            <beans>
                <bean id="A" class="...">
                    <property name="x" value="150" />
                </bean>

                <bean id="B" class="..." scope="prototype">
                    <property name="y" value="20" />
                    <property name="z" value="7" />
                    <property name="w" value="7" />
                    <property name="bclist">
                        <list>
                            <ref bean="C" />
                        </list>
                </bean>

                <bean id="C" class="...">
                    <property name="v" value="3" />
                    <property name="l" value="1" />
                </bean>
            </beans>
```

Java code:

```
  class **A** implements runnable{
    int x;
    Collection<**B**> clist;         //not fixed size list, 
    run(){
       // if (something happens) 
       //           new Thread((B)context.getBean("B"))
    }
  }
```